# Java List, Partition by and Get Last Item in Sort

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a List of ProductTransactions. I want to find the Final (largest) productTransactionId sale for each product in `List<ProductTransaction>` . So I partition this by ProductId, and order by ProductTransactionId.
Final List in example below `List<Integer> (2, 5, 9)`
How can this be done? I am trying to use stream and filter.

```
@Data
public class ProductTransaction {
    private int productTransactionId;
    private int productId;
    private Date saleDate;
    private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

| ProductTransactionId | ProductId | SaleDate | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3/2/2019 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 4/1/2019 | 9 |
| 3 | 2 | 4/1/2019 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 8/21/2019 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 8/21/2019 | 4 |
| 6 | 3 | 10/1/2019 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 | 10/3/2019 | 5 |
| 8 | 3 | 10/3/2019 | 7 |
| 9 | 3 | 10/3/2019 | 8 |

(please ignore the SaleDate, only sort by ProductTransactionId;
The table input data, may not be necessarily sorted

currently using Java 8

**Attempt:**

current Long Solution (want to make cleaner short hand, or perhaps faster performance)

```
Set<Long> finalProductTransactionIds = new HashSet<>();
    
Set<Long> distinctProductIds =  productTransactions.stream()
        .map(ProductTransaction::getProductid)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

for (Long productId: distinctProductIds) {
    Long productTransactionId = productTransactions.stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getProductId() == productId])
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ProductTransaction::getProductTransactionId)
            .reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0).getProductTransactionId();
    finalProductTransactionIds.add(productTransactionId);
}
```

Comment: hi @knittl please assume the table is Not sorted, thanks

Comment: Eritrean's solution is probably as elegant and efficient as you'll find. What are you hoping to achieve with the bounty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind unwrapping Optionals, you can group by your product id and then use a mapping + maxBy downstream collector. This avoids having to collect to a temporary list, as only the last item will be kept (but adds minimal overhead for the optional instances).

```
final Map<Integer, Optional<Integer>> map = transactions.stream()
        .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        ProductTransaction::getProductId,
                        Collectors.mapping(
                                ProductTransaction::getProductTransactionId,
                                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()))));

final Collection<Optional<Integer>> optionalMax = map.values();
final List<Optional<Integer>> max = optionalMax.stream()
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It is also possible to use the special overload of the `toMap` collector to avoid the Optional type:

```
final Collection<Integer> maxTransactionIds = transactions.stream()
        .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        ProductTransaction::getProductId,
                        ProductTransaction::getProductTransactionId,
                        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder())))
        .values();
```

Thanks to [Eritrean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5176992/eritrean) for pointing out that `getProductId` returns an int, so we can replace the generally applicable `BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder)` with the shorter `Math::max` (`Math#max(int,int)`) method reference, which will return the larger value of two integers:

```
final Collection<Integer> maxTransactionIds = transactions.stream()
        .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        ProductTransaction::getProductId,
                        ProductTransaction::getProductTransactionId,
                        Math::max))
        .values();
```

---

And maybe you don't like the Stream API. You can use a regular loop and the `Map#merge` function to achieve the same end result. If you squint, the merge call even looks like the `toMap` collector (why that is, is left as an exercise to the reader :)).

```
final Map<Integer, Integer> maxTxPerProduct = new HashMap<>();
for (final ProductTransaction transaction : transactions) {
    maxTxPerProduct.merge(
            transaction.getProductId(),
            transaction.getProductTransactionId(),
            Math::max);
}
final Collection<Integer> max = maxTxPerProduct.values();
```

It definitely avoids creating stream and collector objects (which is rarely a problem anyway).

Comment: @mattsmith5 yes, correct. It will use the comparator to reduce the stream to the largest item.

Comment: I'll use the answer without optionals, since its a list, its either an empty array (given empty productTransactions), or the final lastIds contains numbers, appreciate it

Comment: Had the same idea as your second approach. You coud replace the binary operator by `Math::max` and save some chars ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Stream over your list and collect to map using `productId` as key and `productTransactionId` as value. If one or more objects share the same `productId`, take the one with the highest `productTransactionId` using `Math::max` and get the values of the map:

```
List<Integer> result =  new ArrayList<>(
        productTransactions.stream()
                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(ProductTransaction::getProductId, 
                                                     ProductTransaction::getProductTransactionId,
                                                     Math::max))
                           .values());
```

To get Partition by First item in sort, just change to `min`

```
List<Integer> result =  new ArrayList<>(
        productTransactions.stream()
                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(ProductTransaction::getProductId, 
                                                     ProductTransaction::getProductTransactionId,
                                                     Math::min))
                           .values());
```

Comment: interesting, are you sorting by productTransactionId largest to smallest ? I dont think getAmount should be used?

Comment: I misunderstood your requierment. I thought you were looking for the transactionId with the highest amount for each productId. I will edit my answer.

Comment: yeah, looking for latest(highest) productTransactionId for each productId, thats what I meant

Comment: this is really good, thanks , lot of improvement, over my original attempt, appreciate it

Comment: by the way, SotiriosDelimanolis (question editor), removed my Java 8 tag? people may utilize Java 11 or Java 14 syntax, that Java 8 does not have, anyways, not a big issue

Comment: Or you could use `collectingAndThen(toMap(...), map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values()))`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with a little bit of collectors and grouping by. You can follow this helpful [article](https://stackabuse.com/guide-to-java-8-collectors-groupingby/) for reference

```
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> productTransactionIdsByProductId = transactionList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    ProductTransaction::getProductId,
                    Collectors.mapping(ProductTransaction::getProductTransactionId, Collectors.toList())));

    final List<Integer> latestTransactionIds = new ArrayList<>();

    productTransactionIdsByProductId.forEach( (k,v)-> {
        if(!v.isEmpty())
            latestTransactionIds.add(v.get(v.size()-1));
    });
    System.out.println(latestTransactionIds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using stream

```
record A(int tId, int pId, double amount) {

}

List<A> list = List.of(
        new A(6, 3, 2),
        new A(7, 3, 5),

        new A(3, 2, 2),
        new A(4, 2, 3),
        new A(5, 2, 4),

        new A(1, 1, 5),
        new A(2, 1, 9),

        new A(8, 3, 7),
        new A(9, 3, 8)
);

Map<Integer, List<A>> grouped = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::pId));

grouped.forEach((integer, as) -> as.sort(Comparator.comparing(A::tId).reversed()));
List<Integer> integers = grouped.values().stream()
        .map(as -> as.stream().map(A::tId).findFirst().orElse(0))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(grouped);
System.out.println(integers);
```

[2, 5, 9]

Answer (score 1):

**BE SIMPLE !!!**

Remember, that support of the code is much more complicated that implemnting. It is better to write smth. with a bit more lines, but much more clear.

E.g. `Streams` are quitre efficient, but sometime much more complicated to realise how it does it's work. In case you can write smth without it, do think about. Probably it can be more clear than streams.

```java
public static List<Integer> getLargest(List<ProductTransaction> transactions) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (ProductTransaction transaction : transactions) {
        int productId = transaction.getProductId();
        map.put(productId, Math.max(map.getOrDefault(productId, 0),
                                    transaction.getProductTransactionId()));
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(new TreeMap<>(map).values());
}
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation why a `TreeMap` is required here and not a regular `HashMap`? Also note that simple in this case can mean slow, because you first have to sort with O(n\*log(n)) complexity. For large input collections, this could be a problem.

Comment: this is on me, because in my question, I asked for simple and good performant, those two criteria are Not the same, it should have been a two part question, however both answers are better than my original attempt, thanks all cc @knittl

Comment: I think, knittl’s version using a loop and `merge` is simpler than using `getOrDefault`, followed by another `put`, avoids the assumption that zero is the minimum value, and is potentially more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to third party libraries, [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) offers some nice helpers for more advanced transformations:

```
List<Integer> result = StreamEx.of(productTransactions)
        .mapToEntry(
                ProductTransaction::getProductId,
                ProductTransaction::getProductTransactionId)
        .collapseKeys(Math::max)
        .values()
        .toList();
```

Comment: looks similar to code above, whats the benefit of this library? faster performance? thanks

Comment: No, it's more of a convenience library for cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

Stream into a map accumulating on the desired key (in your case, productId) but resolving by max amount on map merge when you run into multiple values for the same key - [BinaryOperator.maxBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html#maxBy-java.util.Comparator-) below.

```
List<ProductTransaction> list = List.of(
new ProductTransaction(1,   1,  "3/2/2019", 5),
new ProductTransaction(2,   1,  "4/1/2019", 9),
new ProductTransaction(3,   2,  "4/1/2019", 2),
new ProductTransaction(4,   2,  "8/21/2019",    3),
new ProductTransaction(5,   2,  "8/21/2019",    4),
new ProductTransaction(6,   3,  "10/1/2019",    2),
new ProductTransaction(7,   3,  "10/3/2019",    5),
new ProductTransaction(8,   3,  "10/3/2019",    7),
new ProductTransaction(9,   3,  "10/3/2019",    8));

Map<Integer, ProductTransaction> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(tx -> tx.productId, Function.identity(),
            BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingDouble(tx -> tx.amount.doubleValue()))));


System.out.println(result.values().stream().map(tx -> tx.productTransactionId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

prints: [2, 5, 9]